# SQL Summary of Status total values by Month of Type2 SC Dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, scd

I have a voucher status history table as a type2 slowly changing dimension table  I am trying to get the summary total value of each status by each month before a particular date.  This is my schema and insert code:

```
CREATE TABLE #HDimVouchers(
       [HVoucherKey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [Voucher_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [VoucherStatusKey] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Voucher_amt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,    
       [DateStatusStart] [date] NULL,       
       [DateStatusEnd] [date] NULL
     
)
--drop table #HDimVouchers
insert #HDimVouchers 
values
(10,2,10.00,'2019-01-01','2019-02-15'),
(10,4,10.00,'2019-02-16',null),
(13,4,10.00,'2019-01-10',null),
(11,2,15.00,'2019-01-01',null),
(12,2,20.00,'2019-03-12','2019-03-12'),
(12,4,20.00,'2019-03-13',null),
(15,2,205.00,'2019-05-25','2020-04-24'),
(15,6,205.00,'2020-04-25',null),
(21,2,100.00,'2019-02-16',null)
```

I would like to get a summary to total value by year-month by voucherstatuskey something like the below:

| [Year-Month] | [VoucherStatusKey] | [Amount] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201901 | 2 | 25 |
| 201901 | 4 | 10 |
| 201902 | 2 | 100 |
| 201902 | 4 | 10 |
| 201903 | 4 | 20 |
| 201905 | 2 | 205 |
| 201906 | 2 | 205 |
| 201907 | 2 | 205 |
| 201908 | 2 | 205 |
| 201909 | 2 | 205 |
| 201910 | 2 | 205 |
| 201911 | 2 | 205 |
| 201912 | 2 | 205 |
| 202001 | 2 | 205 |
| 202002 | 2 | 205 |
| 202003 | 2 | 205 |

I have had many attempts to get the data as above, but I am struggling to get the correct format and values. Below is something I have tried

```
SELECT  convert(nvarchar(4),Year([DateStatusStart])) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(Month, [DateStatusStart])), 2)
,[VoucherStatusKey]
,SUM([Voucher_amt]) OVER (PARTITION BY Year([DateStatusStart]),Month([DateStatusStart]), [VoucherStatusKey] ORDER BY [DateStatusStart]) AS running_total 
FROM #HDimVouchers where [DateStatusStart] < '2020-03-31';
```

Comment: The numbers don't make sense.  Where does "25" in the first row come from?  It is not in the original data.

Comment: do you want to get grouped data by month and status key? if yes you can use s.th like ( 
 GROUP BY DATEPART(Month, [DateStatusStart]), [VoucherStatusKey]  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume that you want the value at the end of the month.  Then, you can take the following approach:

- Generate all appropriate months for each voucher.
- Use a `join` to bring in the appropriate value.

For the first part, you could use a tally or calendar table if one is available.  However a recursive CTE is also convenient:

```
with vdates as (
      select voucher_id, eomonth(min(DateStatusStart)) as eom
      from HDimVouchers
      group by voucher_id
      union all
      select voucher_id, eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, eom))
      from vdates
      where eom < '2020-03-01'
     )
select vd.*, hv.Voucher_amt
from vdates vd join
     HDimVouchers hv
     on hv.voucher_id = vd.voucher_id and
        vd.eom >= hv.DateStatusStart and
        (vd.eom <= hv.DateStatusEnd or hv.DateStatusEnd is null)
order by vd.eom, vd.voucher_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f7754b03ac2d98ae16cdf3d8ec43d7b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Bit dodgy just using `eomonth` because eg `select dateadd(month, 1, '2021-02-28')` is `2021-03-28` admittedly you've got out of that with `>= and <=`, but probably better to use `datefromparts(year(DateStatusStart), month(DateStatusStart), 1`

Comment: @Charlieface . . . Good point.  I should use `eomonth()` in both parts of the CTE.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff ...I assume then to get a total by voucher status by eom - we would just need to group by `vd.eom , hv.VoucherStatusKey `

Comment: @Paul . . . Yes, I think that would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this would be:

```
;with [dates] as (
    select YEAR(MIN([DateStatusStart]))*100+MONTH(MIN([DateStatusStart])) [YM] from #HDimVouchers
    union all
    select case when ([dates].[YM] % 100) = 12 then [dates].[YM] + 100 - 11 else [dates].[YM] + 1 end from [dates] where [YM] < 202112
), [dimkeys] as (
    select
        [Voucher_id],
        YEAR(MIN([DateStatusStart]))*100+MONTH(MIN([DateStatusStart])) [DateStatusStart],
        YEAR(MAX(ISNULL([DateStatusEnd], DATEFROMPARTS(2999, 12, 31))))*100+MONTH(MAX(ISNULL([DateStatusEnd], DATEFROMPARTS(2999, 12, 31)))) [DateStatusEnd]
        from [#HDimVouchers] group by [Voucher_id]
), [map] as (
    select
        [dimkeys].[Voucher_id],
        [dates].[YM],
        COALESCE(
            MAX([d].[DateStatusStart]),
            (select MAX([i].[DateStatusStart]) from [#HDimVouchers] [i] where [i].[Voucher_id] = [dimkeys].[Voucher_id] and YEAR([i].[DateStatusStart])*100+MONTH([i].[DateStatusStart]) < [dates].[YM]),
            (select MIN([i].[DateStatusStart]) from [#HDimVouchers] [i] where [i].[Voucher_id] = [dimkeys].[Voucher_id])
        ) [MappingDate]
    from [dates]
    cross join [dimkeys]
    left join [#HDimVouchers] [d] on [d].[Voucher_id] = [dimkeys].[Voucher_id] and YEAR([d].[DateStatusStart])*100+MONTH([d].[DateStatusStart]) = [dates].[YM]
    where [dates].[YM] >= [dimkeys].[DateStatusStart] and [dates].[YM] <= [dimkeys].[DateStatusEnd]
    group by [dimkeys].[Voucher_id], [dates].[YM]
)
select [map].[YM], [fact].[VoucherStatusKey], SUM([fact].[Voucher_amt]) [Sum]
from [map] join [#HDimVouchers] [fact] on [fact].[Voucher_id] = [map].[Voucher_id] and [fact].[DateStatusStart] = [map].[MappingDate]
group by [map].[YM], [fact].[VoucherStatusKey]
order by [YM], [VoucherStatusKey];
```

So:

- Get all year-month values from start to end
- Get all distinct keys with their overall min/max dates (aka when the member exists)
- cross join them to get an entry of every key for every yearmonth (within lifetime of member)
- add the date which should be used for mapping (this is used to decide to which month to add a member that was changed in a year-month)
- only then join this up with the full dimension and group by the SCD Type 2 attribute

---

**Update**

For big tables, you can split it up in multiple temp. tables instead of going all out on CTEs. That usually helps a lot on performance.

```
select *,
    YEAR([DateStatusStart])*100+MONTH([DateStatusStart]) [YmStart],
    YEAR([DateStatusEnd])*100+MONTH([DateStatusEnd]) [YmEnd]
into [#withYm]
from [#HDimVouchers];

;with [dates] as (
    select MIN([YmStart]) [YM] from [#withYm]
    union all
    select case when ([dates].[YM] % 100) = 12 then [dates].[YM] + 100 - 11 else [dates].[YM] + 1 end from [dates] where [YM] < 202112
), [dimkeys] as (
    select
        [Voucher_id],
        MIN([YmStart]) [YmStart],
        MAX(ISNULL([YmEnd], 299912)) [YmEnd]
    from [#withYm]
    group by [Voucher_id]
)
select
    [dimkeys].[Voucher_id],
    [dates].[YM]
into [#all]
from [dates]
cross join [dimkeys]
where [dates].[YM] >= [dimkeys].[YmStart] and [dates].[YM] <= [dimkeys].[YmEnd]

;with [map] as (
    select
        [#all].[Voucher_id],
        [#all].[YM],
        ISNULL(
            MAX([d].[DateStatusStart]),
            (select MAX([i].[DateStatusStart]) from [#withYm] [i] where [i].[Voucher_id] = [#all].[Voucher_id] and [i].[YmStart] < [#all].[YM])
        ) [MappingDate]
    from [#all]
    left join [#HDimVouchers] [d] on [d].[Voucher_id] = [#all].[Voucher_id] and YEAR([d].[DateStatusStart])*100+MONTH([d].[DateStatusStart]) = [#all].[YM]
    group by [#all].[Voucher_id], [#all].[YM]
)
select [map].[YM], [fact].[VoucherStatusKey], SUM([fact].[Voucher_amt]) [Sum]
from [map] join [#HDimVouchers] [fact] on [fact].[Voucher_id] = [map].[Voucher_id] and [fact].[DateStatusStart] = [map].[MappingDate]
group by [map].[YM], [fact].[VoucherStatusKey]
order by [YM], [VoucherStatusKey];
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas-P I have checked this with the example data, and it seems to be doing the summation correctly, but when I take to Data warehouse with many rows I stopped the query after 10mins... :-(

Comment: Thanks for the update @Andreas it is a lot quicker appreciate  your help and effort.